# CORS preflight OPTIONS request returns 401 (Unauthorized) from Windows Authenticated web api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, windows-authentication

I've got a `.NET Web API` project using `Windows Authentication`. In my development environment, I can't do a successful `POST` request with data from my `Angular` app. It returns:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:9090/api/values 401 (Unauthorized)
Failed to load http://localhost:9090/api/values: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
```

I've tried all means of implementing cors with `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` to no avail. But currently I've removed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package from my project in favor of the `web.config` method **(if I actually still need `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` installed to do the following in `Web.config`, plz let me know)**:

**Web.config:**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:5200" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**.NET Web API 'ValuesController.cs':**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Angular Component (sends data to my Angular service):**

```
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.myPost({ID: 1, FirstName: 'Bob'})
    .subscribe(
      data => console.warn(data),
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log("empty")
    );
  }
```

**Angular Service (posts the component's data to my `Web API`):**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  };


  public myPost(body) {

      const httpOptions = {
         withCredentials: true
      }

      return this.http.post("http://localhost:9090/api/values", body, httpOptions);

  }

}
```

From my research it seems that perhaps I need to pass in an `Authorization` header in my request via my `httpOptions` variable in the service. But I don't know what to pass as the value for the `Authorization` property. See the question marks below:
**MyService.ts**

```
  public myPost(body) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': '?????'
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    }
      return this.http.post("http://localhost:9090/api/values", body, httpOptions);
  }
```

Maybe this isn't even my problem though. CORS + Windows Authentication - any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference You must use this IIS module to respond CORS headers for preflight requests. Remove all your custom headers above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing CORS connections from port 4200, which is the default port for Angular applications that use the Angular CLI?

You can also add your headers like this (provided you have a bearer token):

**Change the GET below to be a POST.**

**Using Http**

```
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
          const options = {
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: true
          };

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/api/values', options)
          .map((response: Response) => {
            const stuff = response.json();
            return stuff;
          }).catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
```

**Using HttpClient**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      withCredentials: true
    };

    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:9090/api/values', body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(        
        catchError(this.handleErrors)        
      ).subscribe((result: any) => {
        return Observable.of(result);
      });
```

Comment: I've got CORS origins configured to `port 5200`. I just open my Angular project in `vsCode` and do an `ng serve --port 5200` and I'm attempting to post from there.

Comment: I see. That is not a problem. I was not sure whether you were overriding the default port or not.

Answer (score 0):

Added :

**App_Start/WebApiConfig - Register method:**

```
config.EnableCors();
```

if  does not work, try

FooController:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```